# Summoning Fancybox in Firefox and Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, firefox, fancybox, internet-explorer-9, jquery-events

I am having some trouble summoning Fancybox in Firefox and IE9. This is working fine in Chrome at the moment however.

I have the following in my header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Here is the script I am using to summon Fancybox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
           $(".fancybox").fancybox();
   });
   
   $("#tip5").fancybox({
   'scrolling'                : 'no',
   'titleShow'                : false,
   'onClosed'                : function() {
       $("#login_error").hide();
   }
});     
</script>
```

Firefox console highlights this problem as:

> "TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function"

Here is a link to an online version of the page: [here](http://thirdsectorfilms.com/team.html)

Comment: First, your link doesn't work. Second `$("#tip5").fancybox()` script should also placed inside the `.ready()` method.

Comment: apologies, link is now fixed.

Comment: Check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#support (FAQ tab) No.6

Comment: thanks for your help, i've tried both these but still no change. firefox still returns the message  "TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function"

Comment: As far as I can see you still have `id="tip5"` instead of `class="tip5"`

Comment: Yes, but the problem is no longer there, as this is now working in IE9 and Firefox, through somewhat a mystery as I haven't changed anything. . . thanks for your help anyway.